# WebAPI ASP.NET ¿Error 404 al utilizar GET /api/controlador?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, iis

Tengo problemas al tratar de llenar una tabla mediante AJAX/JSON. Para obtener los datos utilizo como url `/api/controlador`.

Ya agregué la extensión .json y por lo que entiendo, el problema está en que la url que a la que se trata de acceder es `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\api\controlador\`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Edita tu pregunta y agrega el error que tengas.

Comment: ¿Te fue de utilidad la respuesta que te han dado?

Answer (score 1):

Si la url es `C:\inetpub\wwwroot\api\controlador\` esta incorrecto, porque eso no es una url, es una ruta fisica a una carpeta.

No se de cual cliente estas invocando a la webapi, pero tendria que ser algo como:  `http://<sitio>/api/controller`

en este caso si lo invocas como `GET` estarias ingresando al action que definas para ese evento http

Aqui

[Calling a Web API From a .NET Client (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client)

explica como usar el clase `HttpClient` para invocar desde una aplicacion cliente al webapi, es importante notar como define una `BaseAddress` como root del sitio web donde hosteas

Nota: no tienes que agregar ninguna extension .json